# Sum Multiple Values for Same Key in Different Dictionaries Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime, dictionary

I have a filepath full of CSV files. I am using Python `glob` to open them and `csv.DictReader()` to read through them and parse the data into dictionaries with the headers as keys.

The data in the CSV files looks like this:

CSVfile1:

```
Name,A,B,C,D,Date
John,-1,2,4.0,-5.1,3/23/2016
Jacob,0,3,2.0,-2.3,3/23/2016
Jinglehimmer,1,100,5.0,-.1,3/23/2016
```

CSVfile2:

```
Name,A,B,C,D,Date
John,5,4,1.0,-1,3/24/2016
Jacob,0,1,7.0,-.1,3/24/2016
Schmidt,10,9,8,7,3/24/2016
```

I am trying to SUM the data in the `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` columns for each name over a set date period (say the past 2 days). For example, I am trying to get a new list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
{Name: John, A: 4, B: 6, C: 5.0, D: -6.1, Date: 2}
{Name: Jacob, A: 0, B: 4, C: 9.0, D: -2.4, Date: 2}
{Name: Jinglehimmer, etc.}
{Name: Schmidt, etc.}
```

Here is the code I have so far that I know works. This opens each CSV and creates a dictionary for each row and allows me to iterate through the dictionaries:

```
import csv
import glob

path = "."

newdict = {}

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
```

Edit:
I tried simply summing all the key values into a new dictionary, but I run into an int+str error.

```
for k in row.keys():
    newdict[k] = newdict.get(k,0) + row[k]
```

I am also not sure how to filter by the `Date:` key to only get x days of data.

Any help or points in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: What are the bunch of different ways, and what were the problems?

Comment: @PeterWood Good question. I tried to start simple and just sum up all the values across all CSV's. But this breaks because I can't add int and str.

    for k in row.keys():
        newdict[k] = newdict.get(k,0) + row[k]

Comment: Well, put that in your question. That's what you need help with.

Comment: [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can [read csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) and has all the operations you need (sum up columns, group by date...) it's probably easiest to work with that.

Comment: Pandas looks like it will work perfectly. Thanks Swenzel. I'm looking forward to reporting back and answering my own question with a good solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach should work:

```
import csv
import glob
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date


days = 2
since = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time()) - timedelta(days = days)
required_fields = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

path = "."
newdict = {}

output = {}

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
            if datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%m/%d/%Y') >= since:
                name = row['Name']

                try:
                    cur_entry = output[name]
                    entry = {field : cur_entry[field] + float(row[field]) for field in required_fields}
                except KeyError as e:
                    entry = {field : float(row[field]) for field in required_fields}
                    entry['Date'] = days

                output[name] = entry

for name, entry in output.items():                
    print name, entry
```

Which for the data you have given will display:

```
Jacob {'A': 0.0, 'C': 9.0, 'B': 4.0, 'D': -2.4}
Jinglehimmer {'A': 1.0, 'Date': 2, 'C': 5.0, 'B': 100.0, 'D': -0.1}
John {'A': 4.0, 'C': 5.0, 'B': 6.0, 'D': -6.1}
Schmidt {'A': 10.0, 'Date': 2, 'C': 8.0, 'B': 9.0, 'D': 7.0}
```

A `datetime` object can be used to help with measuring the time interval.